# Creating a TCP Socket connection and keep the connection open across several views

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, networking, singleton

I have successfully made a connection from an iPhone to a Server (which is a Windows machine) using TCP sockets.  Currently, I'm using a button to execute the following code:

```
while(1)
{
    Socket *socket;
    int port = 11005;
    NSString *host = @"9.5.3.63";

    socket = [Socket socket];

    @try
    {
        NSMutableData *data;
        [socket connectToHostName:host port:port];
        [socket readData:data];
        //  [socket writeString:@"Hello World!"];

        //** Connection was successful **//
        [socket retain]; // Must retain if want to use out of this action block.
    }
    @catch (NSException* exception) 
    {
        NSString *errMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[exception reason]];
        NSLog(errMsg);
        socket = nil;
    }
}
```

That was the easy part... I'm trying to establish the sockets connection as soon as the app loads.  I tried putting this code in my viewDidLoad, but the loop is infinite and the view never loads.  I have several views in my project, and I'd like to open the connection keep the connection open at all times, across all views.

Objective:

- Open TCP Sockets connection when app first loads
- Maintain connection infinitely, no matter what view I am in (Multiple Views in Project)

I'm still rather new to iOS development, so I appreciate as much clarity as possible.  It should be noted that I am using the SmallSockets library to open my Sockets connection.  Thanks for the help!

*** EDIT ***

Based off the answer below, this is what I've got going so far:

SocketConnection.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SocketConnection : NSObject
{

}

+ (SocketConnection *)getInstance;

@end
```

SocketConnection.m

static SocketConnection *sharedInstance = nil;

```
@implementation SocketConnection

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) 
    {
        while(1)
        {
            Socket *socket;
            int port = 11005;
            NSString *host = @"9.5.3.63";

            socket = [Socket socket];

            @try
            {
                NSMutableData *data;
                [socket connectToHostName:host port:port];
                [socket readData:data];
                //  [socket writeString:@"Hello World!"];

                //** Connection was successful **//
                [socket retain]; // Must retain if want to use out of this action block.
            }
            @catch (NSException* exception) 
            {
                NSString *errMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[exception reason]];
                NSLog(errMsg);
                socket = nil;
            }
        }
    }
    return self;
}

+ (SocketConnection *)getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self) 
    {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) 
        {
            sharedInstance = [[SocketConnection alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

I still have not figured out how the singleton class gets invoked.  I fired up my app with the code from above and it's not connecting to the server.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You will probably want to create a separate class (maybe called `connectionKeeper` or something) and initiate it in `appDelegate` `applicationDidFinishLaunching: withOptions:`. TCP connection has nothing to do with views of viewcontrollers so you should keep it separate.

Comment: Move the code in a singlton class or to the appdelegate

Comment: If I create a separate class, then where is the class "called" so that the socket connection becomes open and remains open?

Comment: Add it to a singlton class, in that way you will only be able to create 1 of this class and access it everywhere

Comment: Right, I'm just trying to understand where I'll create an object of the singleton class.  Forgive my ignorance, I've never worked with singleton classes before.  Thanks for the speedy responses!

Comment: Where did  Socket came from? Where is the definition of this class?  does it exists on iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a singleton classes to keep your connection like below code:

**h file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface SocketConnection : NSObject
    {
    }

     + (SocketConnection *)getInstance;

    @end;
```

**m file:**

```
#import "SocketConnection.h"

static SocketConnection *sharedInstance = nil;

@implementation SocketConnection

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

+ (SocketConnection *)getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[SocketConnection alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end;
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to write out some sample code, but I don't really follow what is going on here.  Would you mind providing a little clarification?  Again, I apologize for the ignorance, but I'm still pretty new to this iOS stuff :)

Comment: Check out the Wiki Article for the Singleton Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern